# Adding Node to LinkedList Not Permanent C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm having a problem where the node being added to my linkedlist is not permanent. Here is my code.

```
void HashMap::add(const std::string& key, const std::string& value) {
    int index = hasher(key) % sizeOfBuckets;
    Node* current = userDatabase[index];
    while (true) {
        if (current == nullptr) {
            current = new Node;
            current->key = key;
            current->value = value;
            current->next = nullptr;
            std::cout << current->key << " " << current->value <<  " at index " << index << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
if (userDatabase[index] == nullptr)
    std::cout << "STILL NULL";
}
```

So far the output **current->key << " " << current->value ...** outputs just fine; however, as you can see at the bottom of my method what happens is **STILL NULL** gets printed out.

Things you need to know...

I'm making a hashmap.
I initialized my entire array of Nodes to nullptr. In the code there I'm creating a node when I encounter nullptr.

Comment: At what point do you think that code adds a node to the linked list?  It doesn't.  It scans through the list and after going past the end, it creates a node but has no way left to connect it.

Comment: The index is definitely the same. And @JSF that's the dilemma here. How would I do so then? I can't think of a way to share the address easily.

Comment: Yeah I'm definitely having trouble trying to settle this. I suppose I could just create the first node in a different block of code, thereby allocating memory that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either adjust the `next` pointer on the previous last node or adjust the head.

Here's the corrected code [sorry for the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
void
HashMap::add(const std::string & key, const std::string & value)
{
    int index = hasher(key) % sizeOfBuckets;
    Node *current = userDatabase[index];
    Node *prev;

    // find the "tail" [last node] of the list [if any] --> prev
    prev = nullptr;
    for (;  current != nullptr;  current = current->next)
        prev = current;

    current = new Node;
    current->key = key;
    current->value = value;
    current->next = nullptr;
    std::cout << current->key << " " << current->value <<
        " at index " << index << std::endl;

    // list is non-empty -- append new node to end of list
    if (prev != nullptr)
        prev->next = current;

    // list is empty -- hook up new node as list "head"
    else
        userDataBase[index] = current;

    if (userDatabase[index] == nullptr)
        std::cout << "STILL NULL";
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still having difficulty understanding how this fixes the issue where current creates a new Node, but then leaves it behind, thereby leaving the new Node to sit in memory. How does the new Node get assigned into userDatabase?

Comment: OH I SEE IT! Thank you!

Comment: @Xari You're welcome!  My apologies.  I've just edited my post to add the clarifying comments in the code that I _should_ have added in the first place.